# how to send data from one ejs file to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, ejs

am working on a node app, i need to get the id of what the user clicked and make it available in another ejs, i tried using local storage, but its not working because local storage is for browsers and node is server.
What other way can i use to achieve it.

this is what item id

```
  <%=item.id%> // home.ejs
```

onclick of this anchor tag should send the id to modals.ejs

```
  <a href="#"><i class="os-icon os-icon-edit"></i><span>Edit</span>
  </a> // home.ejs
```

i also included modal.ejs

```
    <%-include('../includes/modals.ejs') %>
```

Comment: Is `home.ejs` include `modals.ejs` ? And where do you want to get the `item.id` ? client side or server side?

Comment: @Rico, yes it dose, am looping thru an array from the database, that how am getting item, which is the individual item of the array, the id property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have rendering on the client, then the click handler should add it to the in-memory data structure being rendered on the page.

If it is server-side rendering, then you need to POST it to the server, or write a GET route that takes it as a param.

Data does not go "from one file to another file". Wherever the rendering is happening, a function is applying the data structure to the template. So you need to get the value into the data structure and cause a re-render.